# How we can format the box size of timeline highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HIghchart timeline in which I want to modify the specific box width and height.
Ex: I want to modify the width and height of the 3rd box containing some data info.

I have tried to inject below code in the 3rd loop but it doesn't work

```
dataLabels: {
  allowOverlap: false,
  format: '<span style="color:{point.color}"></span>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; width:500px height:660px" > ' +
    '</span><br/>{point.label}'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-timeline/datetime-axis

**Shown in figure I want to increase 3rd box width and height like a squared bracket.**

[image]

Comment: You can try it with selectors. 
```.highcharts-data-label-color-5 rect {width: 100 !important, height: 150 !important}```
Here instead of 5, add the index of the element you want to target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define individual `dataLabel` for a point:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    data: [..., {
        x: Date.UTC(1966, 1, 3),
        dataLabels: {
            useHTML: true,
            borderRadius: 0,
            format: '<div style="height: 100px; width: 200px">{point.name}</div>'
        },
        name: 'First soft landing on the Moon'
    }]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1apcewdt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.data.dataLabels